# Can I configure error notifications on a specific cronjob entry to go to a different email address?

Tags: centos, cron

I have multiple cron job entries configured under a single account:

```
0 0 * * * /foo/foo.sh
0 2 * * * /foo/foo2.sh
0 4 * * * /foo/foo3.sh
```

Right now, if any of these encounter an error, an email is sent to the user account.  Can I configure cron to send a notification to a different email address depending on which entry encounters the error?

For example, if an error occurs while running `/foo/foo.sh` send to bob@bob.com.  If an error occurs while running `/foo/foo2.sh` send to joe@joe.com.

I know I can set `MAILTO=someaddress@example.com`  but I think that's for ALL cron entries (for the account I'm logged in as)... I don't think that's a per-entry setting.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It it perfectly Ok to use `MAILTO=` per-entry, i.e.:

```
MAILTO="address1"
0  0 * * * /foo/foo.sh
MAILTO="address2"
0  2 * * * /foo/foo2.sh
MAILTO="address3"
0  4 * * * /foo/foo3.sh
MAILTO="address4"
0  6 * * * /foo/foo4.sh
0  8 * * * /foo/foo5.sh
0 10 * * * /foo/foo6.sh
```

And so on.

Cheers,

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was possible.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is [what you are looking for](https://serverfault.com/a/33511). From that answer, I see it as,

```
ORIGMAILTO="$MAILTO"
MAILTO=you
* * * ...  your cron job
MAILTO="$ORIGMAILTO"
```